# Put the video tag on the Canvas tag

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, html5-video

I would like to put the video player on Canvas.

(Since my video is alpha channel and I would like to play the video on jpg)

I made code like this below
html

```
<video id="mainVideo" src="item0.mp4">
</video>
<canvas id="mainCanvas">
</canvas>
```

my css

```
#mainCanvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 400;
    height: 400;
}

#mainVideo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300;
    left: 300;
    margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
}
```

my javascript

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('mainCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "image.jpg";
    context.drawImage(img, 0,0)
},false);
```

In my thought,it shows the jpg and video on it.

Howevere, only the jpg appears on it,(video might be concealed by canvas??)

please let me know how can I pay the video on jpg??

My idea (using HTML and canvas together)is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw both images and video on html canvas.

The canvas can use either image objects or video elements as its image source.

Both are drawn using separate `context.drawImage` commands

Here's example code:

```
// reference to canvas and context
var canvas=document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw,ch;

// reference to video element
var v = document.getElementById('mainVideo');

// wait until video metadata is loaded
v.addEventListener( "loadedmetadata", function(e){

    // set the canvas size to the video size
    cw=canvas.width=v.videoWidth;
    ch=canvas.height=v.videoHeight;

    // listen for when user presses play
    v.addEventListener('play', function(){
        // start loop that displays video frames on canvas
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    },false);


}, false );   

// loop that displays video frames on canvas
function animate(time){

    // stop the loop if user stops video
    if(v.paused || v.ended){ return; }

    // draw the 1 current video frame on the canvas
    context.drawImage(v,0,0,cw,ch);

    // also draw your image on the canvas
    context.drawImage(img,0,0);

    // request another loop 
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

}
```

Comment: Thanks!! it is great answer for me. I understood I need to refresh image each frames by this animate function.