# Attach an image to a moving element in a video using canvas

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas, chromakey

How can I create a video using HTML5 canvas where I can attach a persons face on a moving element in a video using chroma key. So that the face moves along with that element.

Came across this website [JibJab](http://www.jibjab.com/ecards) which makes use of this.

Just want to know how this can be done using HTML5 canvas.

As per my research we can place a video on a video or even a static image (http://www.xindustry.com/html5greenscreen/). But how to move a static image is what I'm looking for.

Also found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34255016/3008050) but it will create transparent element in the video and not attach an image to it.

Comment: For known videos, you could store all the positions based on the `currentTime` of your video,e.g in a json (`"myPos":{"12":{"x":40,"y":30}, 13:{"x": 43, "y":32}...}` then just get the position from it : `var pos = myPos[~~vid.currentTime]; drawImage(yourFace, pos.x, pos.y)` over the video frame (drawn thanks to `drawImage(yourVid, 0,0)`). For unknown videos, you'll have to have some sort of a marker in your video that you'll have to read from  `getImageData()`'s `data`.

Comment: @Kaiido yes i have a croma marker in my video. I can detect the chroma pixel by running a loop. But can i get the coordinates of that marker in a frame so i can set the position dynamically instead of the static json?

Comment: So what you need is to convert the imageData's index to x,y coordinates ? `var px = i / 4; var y = Math.floor(px / canvas.width); var x = Math.round(((px/canvas.width) - y ) * canvas.width);` But running `getImageData` over a video is really not somethign I would advise to anyone, moreover on unknown client configs. You would be better doing it once, and store the positions in a json.

Comment: @Kaiido yes got your point. Will give this logic a try. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @karan3112 Is this implemented ? I'm trying similar to jibjab.

Comment: @Shahil No. I had tried to implement this and it was close to that marker. But didn't complete it.

Comment: @karan3112 any idea about the implementation ? I need to add a face image to existing video.

Comment: @Shahil No but you can give Kaiido's logic a try.